# copied /etc folder to new laptop can't reboot

Tags: grub2

I copied my /etc from old ubuntu 16.04 installation to new, upon advice on migration http://eggsonbread.com/2010/01/28/move-ubuntu-to-another-computer-in-3-simple-steps

maybe I should've just moved some, or name my machine the same name.  Anyway now's there's a conflict, when I try and reboot, it goes to a screen showing

```
 [FAILED] Failed to start remount root and kernal file system 
  Welcome to emergency mode! after logging type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" Press enter for maintenance (or Control-D to continue)
```

if I press enter I get my old laptop machine name prompt

```
    root@old-laptop:~#
```

systemctl just takes me back to the GNU GRUB screen back where I started.

wondering if there's solution, as I can't even reinstall ubuntu.  Maybe need to reformat the SSD.

Comment: That link doesn't say to copy the entirety of `/etc`. The problem is probably that `/etc/fstab` was replaced, though you should probably reinstall to ensure that all files are installed properly rather than fixing only that.

Comment: FSTAB = file system table; or what gets mounted on boot & options for them.  You copied that file as prior comments say; which means you system wants the HDD to perfectly match the old computer, which it doesn't so it follows options also found in the file which cause the errors (ie. something is suspect so it refuses to boot).  You'll have to modify at least your `fstab` to reflect the new hdd (be it /dev/sd?? if that's how partitions are referred; or the more unique UUID's which cause exactly what you're experiencing...) then find what other things you've overwritten...  (eg. machine-name..)